# span delegate click - can not click above disabled checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am having issues clicking the area in the span where the disabled checkbox is.  I read that the best way to get around not being able to click a disabled checkbox is to wrap it in a span.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  (probably something simple).
[Broken JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/y9bnT/)

```
<ul class="field">
  <li><span>Test A <label for="id_check1">Check 1</label>: 
       <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="1" id="id_check1" /></span></li>

  <li><span>Test B <label for="id_check2">Check 2</label>: 
       <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="2" id="id_check2" /></span></li>

  <li><span>Test D <label for="id_check3">Check 3</label>: 
     <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="3" id="id_check3" disabled="disabled" /></span></li>
</ul>


$('li').delegate('span', 'click', function(event) {
    alert('clicked');
    #this is here bc the real example has anchors
    event.preventDefault();
   }
);​
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. When do you want the alert triggered?

Comment: Hiya, I tried clicking right above the checkbox  and it did fired an event, **or is it something else**, me on OSX lion / chrome, cheers - http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/y9bnT/

Comment: You clicked above the disabled checkbox ?

Comment: I click the d checkbox, and I do not see a "click" alert...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled input elements don't register click events. You can place another element on top of it and grab the click on that however (see the div in the third list item). See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y9bnT/3/)**.

jQuery:

```
$('li').on('click', 'div', function(event){ 
    alert('clicked');
);​
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="field">
    <li><span>Test A <label for="id_check1">Check 1</label>:
    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="1" id="id_check1" /></span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Test B <label for="id_check2">Check 2</label>:
    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="2" id="id_check2" /></span>
    </li>
    <li style='position: relative'>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;">
    </div>
    <span>Test D <label for="id_check3">Check 3</label>:
    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="3" id="id_check3" disabled="disabled" /></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because it lies behind or under the checkbox.

Comment: I put the span in there to try to do the same, so I will remove it and use the div.

Comment: Also by positioning the div absolutely you remove it from the normal flow of the document and can lay it on top of another element, here the input.

Comment: This is nice in our test program but how do I postion it so it stays within the li ?  Right now its taking up half my page ;)

Comment: You can add a width attribute to the div if that's causing the issue.

Comment: I had to add  <li style='position: relative'> and it sized appropriately, add it to your solution and I will accept.

Comment: You added the position:relative to each list item, or just to the one with the div in it? I'm assuming you added it inline versus a separate CSS style declaration.

Comment: I dont care if its on the li or style, if you dont specify it, the absolute div takes up half the page.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to fire a function when clicking a checkbox:

1.Sets for all checkboxs

2.checks if checkbox is disabled and does nothing, else does something you want

```
$(":checkbox").bind('each click', function(e){
if($(this).is('disabled')){
    e.preventDefault();
}else{
  ///Do something here         
}
});
```